# start/play video player onClick of image for LeadPlayer (or any Player)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, video

I would like to figure out a way to get my image when clicked on to autoplay my media player. I'm a bit new and can't figure out onclick for this matter. I suppose jquery is the way to go. So, Thanks in advanced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>#leadplayer_video_element_5348CAD9E1F02
<head>
<style>
<style>
position:absolute;
left:8px;
top:8px;
z-index:-1;
}
</style>
</head>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
<img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/1508520_496016637195955_3564444582693127544_n.png" hight="294" width="377" onclick="this.style.display='none';" style="position:absolute;opacity:1.0; z-index:1;"/>
</a>

<!-- LeadPlayer video embed code start [ video: 5348CAD9E1F02 ] -->
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.leadbrite.com/leadplayer/r0034/js/leadplayer.js">
</script>
</div>
<div id="leadplayer_video_element_5348CAD9E1F02" style="width:377px;height:260px">
</div>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">jQLeadBrite("#leadplayer_video_element_5348CAD9E1F02").leadplayer(false, "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");
</script>
</div>
<!-- LeadPlayer video embed code end [ video: 5348CAD9E1F02 ] -->

</body>
</html>
```

OR... Can anyone find a way to make the pic refresh in the same div using ajax and jquery? Both would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery Lib in head section

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">`

Try this (Add inside `<script>..code..</script>`)

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.player').slideToggle();
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RTrZh/2/)

Comment: Thank you but this did not work. Does it have to do with the video Player? it uses a youtube video, but changes to a new format when in the LeadPlayer.